# vb6 query: how to open table, that declared in textbox

Tags: vb6

```
private Command1_Click()

        Dim a as string

        a = text1.text
        OpenQuery "SELECT * FROM a WHERE Chair;"

        txtChair.Text = myRs.Fields(0).Value

        myRs.MoveNext
    loop 

end sub
```

Comment: please think again: how can it be possible to put an unknown number of rows (and because of the * in your select an unknown number of columns) in a single textbox. take a look at datagrid or similiar components. flexgrid is part of vb6 (although it has to be installed separetly, as far as i remember)

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample is missing a an opening `Do` statement, possibly an over site. Also, @nabuchodonossor is correct in that at best a the end of the loop the value of field(0) for the last record will be in txtChair.Text. But what you're asking for help with is to build a single string query where you are substituting a variable value for part of the string.

```
Private Command1_Click()
    Dim a as string

    a = text1.text
    'this query isn't right, but not sure what to do with it
    'this is something like normally "WHERE Field = 'Chair'"
    OpenQuery "SELECT * FROM " & a & " WHERE Chair;"  'The & concatenates the separate strings

    Do While rs.EOF = False
        txtChair.Text = myRs.Fields(0).Value
        myRs.MoveNext
   Loop 

End Sub
```

[MSDN link to the & Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242763(v=vs.60).aspx)